# How to download returned file (attachment) via php?

Tags: php, http, download

I have some link to page, when I go to this page via browser (Firefox) there is pop-up window that offering to download that file. I saw HTTP headers when make request to this page and it return me the next answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.3.17
Date: Thu, 16 Jan 2014 20:00:46 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 183855
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 20:43:42 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

The `file_get_contents` function doesn't work in this case. How can I download that file using only PHP?

**UPDATE**

I'm using the next code:

```
$url = 'http://example.com' . $matches[1];
$path = 'jpgs/' . $matches[2];
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($url));
```

Data in the url and path variable exactly correct.

Comment: Why didn't file_get_contents work?

Comment: @Scopey I don't know, it's returning me the empty string.

Comment: Can you post your code which includes the file_get_contents?

Comment: @Scopey, I'm updated my answer with code.

Comment: `file_put_contents` after a `file_get_contents` should work fine like that. Try echoing out exactly what URL you are generating, and then making sure your `file_get_contents` is returning something before putting it.